# Java XPath - select all nodes does not work with namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to select all elements (in my case **//ab**) from given XML. But it does not select anything (matches variable contains empty list):

```
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ab");

    NodeList matches = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            ("<x:xml xmlns:x=\"yyy\">"+
                    "<x:ab>123</x:ab>"+
             "</x:xml>").getBytes())), XPathConstants.NODESET); 
    if (matches != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = (Node) matches.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue()); 
        }
    }
```

Interesting is when change the xpath to : ***//ab** , then it does select the **ab** element.

Also when I remove namespace from xml then the xpath **//ab** does select the **ab** element.

Same as when I add namespaceContext to xpath object and add namespace to xpath query: **//x:ab** , then it does select the **ab** element.

How should I change the code, so I would get **ab** element without changing the query?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Your XML uses namespaces, so your XPath must be aware of namespaces.  You've enumerated all the options, choose one.

Comment: but why *//ab selects the ab element even when the xml contains namespace? and also /xml/ab works...

Comment: The context node is the document, and the wildcard `*` selects all element children of the context node, regardless of their namespace.  This is then further qualified with a step `//ab` that filters the resulting node set. If you use the XPath `//ab` now you are specifying `ab` nodes _with no namespace_.  It's subtle but different.